# Storing text in database with tags

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me with this? I want to know how to store text in database with the tags. For example, if the text is bold, italics, underlined, justification, paragraphs, space etc., then even that must be retrieved and displayed in the textarea of the jsp page. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

use function `getTag("id_of_tag")` to get tag.

attached its value and save it to database.Later retrieve it and show in view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a field in database with datatype `Text`
2. Use some javascript text-area such as [`tinymce`](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/full.php) so that user can enter the text bold, italic etc.
3. Save the field with proper sql injectioning after form submission.